# How can I make a bukkit/spigot minecraft server on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, minecraft

I have no experience with ubuntu, I just know how to use the terminal, and install stuff. I have little knowlage in programming. Anything is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You must first download the MC server.  This location will vary depending on which version you want, but let's assume the main file is `mcserver.jar`.

In my experience, you must install java:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

and then you can start the server by running

```
java -jar mcserver.jar
```

Note:  If you have a firewall running, you will likely need to open the correct ports for MC.